# Plugin Using get_the_content Causing Issues With <!--more--> Tag

Tags: plugins, the-content

I'm testing out the Woothemes "Our Team" plugin to see how it works for future project purposes.

The plugin uses at CPT for Team Members as well as a shortcode to allow users to display members on a page.

The issue that I'm bumping into is that the content that is output by the shortcode is not honoring the `<!--more-->` tag.  I'm assuming it's because in the [woothemes-our-team-template.php](https://github.com/woothemes/our-team/blob/master/woothemes-our-team-template.php) file on line 196 it's using `get_the_content` as shown below:

`$content = apply_filters( 'woothemes_our_team_content', wpautop( get_the_content() ), $post );`

It appears that there is also a filter that should be able to be hooked into called "woothemes_our_team_content" but no matter what I try to add into my functions.php I can't get it to recognize that there is a `<!--more-->` tag.  All my efforts have only managed to remove all the content.

Essentially I'd like to hook into the filter, have it recognize the `<!--more-->` tag, and then change "Read More" to say "Read Full Bio...".

Doe anyone have any suggestions on the best way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logical fork between displaying full content and teaser (that's what part from start of post to more tag is called) is ruled by `$more` global variable. Which depends on other global stuff and so on, important point being it's not set to `0` when you want it to be. Likely because you are running this in context when it wouldn't be set to zero for normal loop either.

Something like this should work:

```
add_filter( 'woothemes_our_team_content', function () {
    global $more;
    $real_more = $more;
    $more      = 0;
    $output    = wpautop( get_the_content() );
    $more      = $real_more;

    return $output;
} );
```

You can just work with link there, or hook into `the_content_more_link` to customize it.